# update tables data from updated table - using merge-sql server and my sql

Tags: mysql, sql-server, merge

I have two tables with at least 25 columns.

1. customers
2. updated_customers

The columns names are the same.

Every day I have some changes in  the columns
Some are added, some are deleted and some are changed
I want to use merge to update from customers (target table)  from updated_customers (source table).

Merge code to do that is:

```
merge into customers trg
using 
(
select 
    [customerid]
    ,[type]
    ,[first_name]
    ,[Last_Name]
    ,[Email]
    ,[Phone]
    ,[sale_status]
    ,[verification]
    ,[campName]
From updated_customers ) src

on src.[ customerid] =trg.[ customerid] 

when matched then
update set
    trg.[ customerid]=src.[ customerid]
    ,trg.[ type]=src.[ type]
    ,trg.[ first_name]=src.[ first_name]
   ,trg.[ Last_Name]=src.[ Last_Name]
    ,trg.[ Email]]=src.[ Email]]
    ,trg.[ Phone]=src.[ Phone]
    ,trg.[ sale_status]=src.[ sale_status]
    ,trg.[ verification]=src.[ verification]
    ,trg.[ campName]=src.[ campName]



when not matched then
insert(trg.[customerid],trg.[ type]…)
values(src.[ customerid],src.[type]…);

END


merge into customers as trg
using 
(
select 
    distinct [customerid]
    from updated_customers) src

    on src.[customerid] =trg.[customerid] 

    when not matched then
    insert(customerid, …..)
    values(src.[customerid],…));



 END
```

How can I do that for all the columns at once?

Check the changes in row-

If nothing changed – do nothing.

If changed – update the changes and mark it in some way.

If added then (that is not the problem).

I have at least 10 tables to do the same.

Comment: How do you mean you're using sql-server AND mysql?

Comment: I have one database in Linux (so i'm using mysql) - but i need to use mssql (company request)  - I have a replication running from mysql to mssql, it takes a very long time. I need it to be faster  - so i want to use merge , and transfer only the new data (updated or just new)  to mssql. I'll be happy to hear some ideas to do that in other way